# VPS: How to set a limit to the monthly bandwidth

Tags: ubuntu, vps, bandwidth

I have a VPS with Ubuntu installed, want to limit the maximum bandwidth to 300 GB at month. Currently I only use a few GB per month, just for safety I want to do this.

What is the best way ?

Should act on Apache or at the level of OS ?

Answer (score 0):

See here: [How to cap bandwidth usage on AWS EC2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/180136/how-to-cap-bandwidth-usage-on-aws-ec2)

It is about EC2, but applies to any *ix server.